# XmlRoot without namespace can't use same ElementName for different type

Tags: c#, wcf, serialization

I have WCF objects like below

```
    [XmlRoot("Result")]
    public class Result0:IXmlSerializable
    {
         public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
         public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { xxx; }
         public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) { xxx; }
    }

    [XmlRoot("Result")]
    public class Result1:IXmlSerializable
    {
         public XmlSchema GetSchema() { return null; }
         public void ReadXml(XmlReader reader) { xxx; }
         public void WriteXml(XmlWriter writer) { xxx; }
    }
```

when I build this WCF application I'll get below error

```
InvalidOperationException: The top XML element 'Result' from namespace '' references distinct types
```

I know I can add option NameSpace param in XmlRoot to resolve this conflict. But what I want is get Xml without any xmlns

```
<Result>
    <xxxx></xxxx>
</Result>
```

Is there a solution for that?

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static XmlDocument RemoveXmlns(XmlDocument doc)
    {
        XDocument d;
        using (var nodeReader = new XmlNodeReader(doc))
            d = XDocument.Load(nodeReader);

        d.Root.Descendants().Attributes().Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();

        foreach (var elem in d.Descendants())
            elem.Name = elem.Name.LocalName;

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        using (var xmlReader = d.CreateReader())
            xmlDocument.Load(xmlReader);

        return xmlDocument;
    }

    public static XmlDocument RemoveXmlns(String xml)
    {
        XDocument d = XDocument.Parse(xml);
        d.Root.Descendants().Attributes().Where(x => x.IsNamespaceDeclaration).Remove();

        foreach (var elem in d.Descendants())
            elem.Name = elem.Name.LocalName;

        var xmlDocument = new XmlDocument();
        xmlDocument.Load(d.CreateReader());

        return xmlDocument;
    }
```